# Google analytics showing WECHAT_EMPTY_TITLE as a page title

Tags: google-analytics, page-title

Google analytics is showing WECHAT_EMPTY_TITLE as a Page Title in **Behaviour --> All pages** report for few pages for website even page title is totally different in those pages which we can look at with view-source.

Did anyone recently see this behavior in google analytics?

Comment: If it's not something WeChat knows it could be spam / bot traffic, do you have bot filter ticked in View Properties?

Comment: Yes "Exclude all hits from known bots and spiders" check box is checked for this view

Comment: What title do those pages actually have? There is something that leads back to wechat (widgets, plugins, etc ...)

Comment: actually page title is different which we can see with view-source and look at <title> element which is not WECHAT_EMPTY_TITLE definitely. Still investigation is going on

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very late response since I ran into this myself at work and there are no other sources about this issue. I'm not actually a dev so if anyone can complete this answer with more technical details (if needed), that would be helpful.

Are you returning the 404 status code when a webpage is not found within your domain? If you return 200 and redirect to a friendly "not found" page, Analytics will record it as a regular page access within your domain.

Chances are someone accidentally managed to access yourwebsite.com/WECHAT_EMPTY_TITLE and analytics tracked it because it was deemed a successful request. This was our problem and it went away once we started returning 404 instead.